# Convert this for loop into a while loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, converters, user-input

Trying to convert this code for a for loop into a while loop:

```
int endData = myScanner.nextInt();   
int row     =   0;
int cell    =   0;
int rowcell =   0;


    System.out.println("FOR LOOP: ");
    for (row = 1; row <= endData; row++) {

        if (row%2 == 0) {
            for (cell = 0; cell < row; cell++) {
                for (rowcell = 0; rowcell <= cell; rowcell++) {
                    System.out.print(row);
                }
                    System.out.println("");
            }

        }

         else {

            for (cell = row; cell > 0; cell--) {
                for (rowcell = cell; rowcell > 0; rowcell--) {
                    System.out.print(row);  
                }
                    System.out.println("");
            }

        }

    }
```

So far I have tried this code but it came out completely wrong:

```
    row2 = 1;

    while (row2 <= endData){

        if(row2%2 == 0){
            cell2=0;
            rowcell2 = 0;
            while(cell2<row2){
                cell2++;
                while(rowcell2 <= cell2){
                    rowcell2++;
                    System.out.print(row2);
                } System.out.println("");
        }

    }else {
        cell2=row2;
        rowcell2 = cell2;
        while(cell2 >0){
            cell2--;
        }while (rowcell2>0){
            rowcell2--;
            System.out.print(row2);
        }System.out.println("");
    } row2++;
    }
```

For example, when the user inputs a value of 3, the for loop returns the correct answer:
1
2
22
333
33
3

But the while loop outputs:
1
22
2
333

Any ideas as how to go about fixing this while loop?

Comment: Why do you want to make  this a while loop? This is the perfect use case for when to use a for loop.

Comment: It's for an assignment!

Answer (score 0):

One of the mistakes i see is the initialisation

```
rowcell2 = 0;
```

it should be under

```
while(cell2<row2){
```

Answer (score 0):

cell is incremented at the end of the for loop and for (cell2) at the beginning of the while loop. Other problems may exist as well.

for loops execute the final section (cell++, etc) at the end of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do to convert it is declare the index before the while loop and add the incrementer to the end of the while loop.

```
int endData = myScanner.nextInt();   
int row     =   0;
int cell    =   0;
int rowcell =   0;


System.out.println("FOR LOOP: ");
row = 1;
while(row <= endData) {

    if (row%2 == 0) {
        cell = 0;
        while (cell < row) {
            rowcell = 0;
            while (rowcell <= cell) {
                System.out.print(row);
                rowcell++;
            }
                System.out.println("");
             cell++;
        }
        row++;
    }

     else {
        cell = row;
        while (cell > 0;) {
            for (rowcell = cell; rowcell > 0; rowcell--) {
                System.out.print(row);  
                cell--;
            }
                System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```